# Run UNetbootin from Live CD

Tags: 13.04, unetbootin

Is it possible to run Unetbootin from Live CD, I need it to install Ubuntu but I can't open because I can't set it as executable

Comment: Yes you can install softwares when you are on live CD but when you restart it will go meaning it wont be persistent. You can install and useit within that session

Answer (score 0):

if that is your real name.
I have had trouble(s) with uNetBootin. If it is a live ubuntu CD you want why cant you just burn a ubuntu disc image onto a CD/DVD

Hope this helped...

Comment: I have Ubuntu 12.04 on CD. Currently I don't have any OS installed on my PC so I'm trying to make Ubuntu usb to install Ubuntu. I don't want to install 12.04 just to make bootable usb drive

Answer (score 0):

You can install the program if you're using a LIVE CD-RW/USB. Surely you won't be able to install the program in a CD / DVD disk. **Speaking in a traditional sense**.

The program could be "installed" for **one-time use**. It would be saved in memory. After you reboot, it would disappear. But when using a real live usb, for example, it would be "installed" in the media.

So basically You can Install Unetbootin and make a Live usb from live CD as long as the system is not restarted after installation.